# PowerShell Event Viewer Errors

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am running a PowerShell script which I have a list of IDs in a text file that matches to files on a server and then Robocopy copies them to other servers.  Recently a file that is present on a server doesn't get copied to 1 out of 2 destinations.  The weird thing is it only happens approximately 10 files out of 500.
I am seeing weird errors in EventViewer.  Would this cause the issue?

> Event ID 400 Engine state is changed from None to Available.
>
> Details:      NewEngineState=Available    PreviousEngineState=None
>
> Event ID 403
>
> Engine state is changed from Available to Stopped.
>
> Details:      NewEngineState=Stopped  PreviousEngineState=Available

Changing copy-item to robocopy in the scripts

```
$CC="S:\CC 2019"
$Daily_Results="S:\~Copy_Move Daily Results\"
$Missing_Files = "S:\~Missing Files\Results\"
$Lab = "\\********\E-Drive\Logs\Files"
$Source = "S:\"


foreach ($ID in Get-Content 'S:\~Master CSC Location Files\CC_Listings.txt') {
$ID
$Count=0
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where  {$_.name -match $ID} |foreach {
        $Path="S:\"+$_.name
        Robocopy $Source $Lab $_.name /COPY:DAT /IS
        Robocopy $Source $CC $_.name /MOV /IS
        Write-Host $_.name 
        "File copied"
        Write-Output $ID "File copied" | Out-File $Daily_Results\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)_CC_CopyMove_Results.txt -append
        Write-Output $_.name | Out-File $Daily_Results\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)_CC_CopyMove_Results.txt -append
        $Count++

}
If($Count –eq 0){
        Write-Host $ID "No File Found"
        Write-Output $ID "No File Found at $(get-date -f hh:mm:ss)"  |  Out-File $Missing_Files\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)_CC_Missing_Files_Results.txt -append
        }
}
```

Comment: Add the `/v` flag to the `robocopy` calls in order to get verbose output including any file it might have skipped

Comment: Thanks Mathias... I will add that function.  Does /v store the skipped file data somewhere so I can analysis it afterwards?

Comment: @bdd23 - you will need to enable logging in RC or capture the output to a $Var in PoSh. i would use robocopy builtin logging ... [*grin*]

Comment: Can anyone explain these errors?

Event ID 400 
Engine state is changed from None to Available.
Details: NewEngineState=Available PreviousEngineState=None

Event ID 403
Engine state is changed from Available to Stopped.
Details: NewEngineState=Stopped PreviousEngineState=Available